# Accessing .net core dll using python

Tags: c#, .net, python-2.7, .net-core, windows-7

I need to access a C# dll which is built in .net core (.NETCore version = v1.1). I tried in the below way but I am getting the import error.

```
import clr

clr.AddReference("dllname") - No error

from dllname import *
```

Got Import Error exception saying no module named *dllname*.

Note: I tried in both Iron python and python both are giving me the same exception.

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying on Fedora 29, using mono 5.18, python3.7 and netcore 3.0.100-preview-009812,
and seems to work if you use absolute paths to resolve the netcore dll

```
import clr
import os

clr.AddReference(os.path.abspath('./bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/sample.dll'))
import sample
p = sample.Person(name='Peter')
```

netcore project was generated like that

```
dotnet new classlib -o sample
```

Person class

```
using System;

namespace sample
{
    public class Person
    {
            public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Based on data provided by @SMHP seems like an incompatibility between main .NET framework/mono (pythonnet runtime) and a library targeting .netcoreapp 2.0.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i tried but didn't worked for me.

Comment: just to get more information. In which operating system are you trying? and what python version ? Can you try previous minimum sample ?

Comment: I just tried in windows 10 with python2.7 and netcore 2.2, works just fine. Can you give more information about the dll you're trying to load ? is it possible that exist some kind of conflict between another python module with the same name ?

Comment: i have installed pythonnet 2.3.0 to access the .net dll's, also installed .net core sdk version 2.2.105.i confirmed that there is no existing python module in that dll's name.i have got this dll from other team, i believe its built in 64 bit computer.

Comment: // xxxx, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

// Global type: <Module>
// Architecture: AnyCPU (64-bit preferred)
// Runtime: .NET 4.0


[assembly: CompilationRelaxations(8)]
[assembly: RuntimeCompatibility(WrapNonExceptionThrows = true)]
[assembly: TargetFramework(".NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1", FrameworkDisplayName = "")]

Answer (score 0):

You get import error because you are using dllname in import statement. Instead of using dllname use namespace of the dll.
P.S: don't use same name for dll and namespace it will throw an error while importing in python

```html
import clr

clr.AddReference("dllname") - No error

from namespace import *
```